# Create a mobile webapp that only opens your website

Tags: android, ios, react-native, ionic2, nativescript

I have a website. I want to create a cross platform webapp that only opens mywebsite if there is access to the internet. Think of this as a website on the browser without address bar. Which framework should I choose to build it easily? I have no prior experience with mobile webapps that is why I look for the easiest way to do this. And how I can achieve this.

Comment: Just wrap your website inside of a Cordova container. You can find more information [in this link](https://auth0.com/blog/converting-your-web-app-to-mobile/).

Answer (score 1):

Talking about android, you can use WebView component with constant URL to open your website. 
In your IOS version use react-native you can also use that component

[React-native (for IOS) component](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html)

[Android component](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)

Comment: Can't I do both of them by using React-native?

Comment: You can, but no guarantees, that your app will have similar representation both on android and ios

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to write just once in order to produce two applications, you could use NativeScript.

Use the connectivity cross-platform module to monitor the internet connectivity - https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/connectivity#getting-connection-type

And the web-view module to display your webpage - https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/ui/web-view